# $f: (\mathbb R^2,\|\cdot\|_\infty)\to \mathbb R$, $f(x , y) =2x+3y$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Show that

$$f: (\mathbb R^2,\|\cdot\|_\infty)\to \mathbb R, \ \ f(x , y) =2x+3y$$

is uniformly continuous. I actually know how to do this exercise or the concept atleast but im kinda stuck with the norm since its one of the very few times im working wth norms so I would like to get my exercise checked and corrected if done wrong. Thanks for your time in advance.

So my approach is let $\epsilon>0$ and $d=? $ I leave it blank will fill it later as i finish the exercise.

So let $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ and $k\in\{1,2\}$ such that

\begin{align}
|x_k + y_k| &= \max \{|x_1 + y_1|,|x_2 + y_2|\} < d \\[.2cm]
\implies(f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)) &= |2x_1+3y_1-2x_2-3y_2|\\&\leq 2|(x_1-x_2)|+3|(y_1-y_2)| \leq 5|x_k + y_k| \\&<5d=\epsilon 
\end{align}
so i also add my $d=\frac{e}{5}$ here.

ps: added an extra line to make my proof even more clear.

Comment: Shouldnt $|x_k + y_k|$ Be  $|x_k + y_k|_\infty$ instead?

Comment: Is that true? Coz this function grows unboundedly on infinity. I would just consider points on the line $y=x$ to check for this property

Comment: @Ilya It doesn't matter that the function goes to infinity, what matters is that the GROWTH of the function stays constant,  so it doesn't matter where in the plane you are,  being close in $x$ and $y$ guarantees that you are close in $2x+3y$

Comment: ah yes, it has a global Lip constant of 5, sure @Alan

Answer (score 1):

You somehow screwed up the arguments of the function $f$. I would moreover, since you mentioned $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ explicitly in the definition of $f$, use that both $|x_1-y_1|\le\|x-y\|_\infty$ and $|x_2-y_2|\le\|x-y\|_\infty$ instead of this $k$-choice...

Comment: Could you be more specific? i understand the 2nd proposal but how exactly i messed up the arguments?

Comment: You define points $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ and when you put them into $f$ you interchange the roles of $x_2$ and $y_1$. You actually should consider the term $|f(x)-f(y)|$  and estimate it. (You also put parentheses instead of $|$ around this term, but I guess this is a typo)

Comment: it was a typo indeed, could you also check my comment

Comment: So the answer to your comment is no as the "instead" expression doesn't really make sense. Do you know how $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is defined?

Comment: yes according to my book $||\cdot||_\infty : R^n \to R$ with$||x||_\infty = max[x_1,x_2...]$

Comment: But then what is $|x_k+y_k|_\infty$ if $x_k$ and $y_k$ are just real numbers, i.e. components of your vectors?